# How to orde or do sth from an activity for another?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, contextmenu, helper

Simple what I want to say.
I have an application that has two activities.(Activity 1 and Activity 2)
in Activity1 I have a Media player that Automatically starts a music song.

I know how to pause the Music in Activity1 but I dont know how to pause or stop it in Activity2 with a Button??

this is Activity1 Code...

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

        final MediaPlayer player = 
        MediaPlayer.create(Activity1.this,R.raw.track);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.setVolume(100,100);
        player.start();
```

Comment: Use a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: but how?? can you help me

Comment: i really need this...please tell me the code